# Configure array/object indentation for YAML in Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson, yaml

I'm trying to generate a YAML file from an input Map I'm using Jackson and the YamlFactory utility provided by Jackson to do so. I'm attempting to configure the indentation property for the YAML output, but it doesn't seem like that's being respected at all.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
fun getSdkResultAsGenericObject(sdkResult: Any?): Any? {
        if (sdkResult == null) {
            return null
        }

        var genericObj: Any?
        val stringified = genericSdkObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(sdkResult)
            .replace("\n", "") 

        val isArray = stringified.startsWith("[")

        genericObj = if (isArray) {
            genericSdkObjectMapper.readValue(stringified, List::class.java)
        } else {
            genericSdkObjectMapper.readValue(stringified, LinkedHashMap::class.java)
        }

        val defaultYaml = resultYamlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(genericObj )
    }
```

The declaration of the resultYamlMapper is like this:

```
    val yamlFactory = YAMLFactory()
                        .configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.SPLIT_LINES, false)
                        .configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.INDENT_ARRAYS, true)
    val resultYamlMapper = ObjectMapper(YamlFactory())
```

The documentation says that the `INDENT_ARRAYS` feature uses 2 spaces by default. I'm trying to understand how I can configure that? I need 4 spaces in the resultant YAML. I tried setting a pretty print writer:

```
    val yamlFactory = YAMLFactory()
                        .configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.SPLIT_LINES, false)
                        .configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.INDENT_ARRAYS, true)
    val resultYamlMapper = ObjectMapper(YamlFactory())
    
    val arrayIndenter = DefaultIndenter("     ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF)
    val objectIndenter = DefaultIndenter("     ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF)

    resultYamlMapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(DefaultPrettyPrinter().withObjectIndenter(objectIndenter).withArrayIndenter(arrayIndenter))
```

But this doesn't seem to be respected at all. Any thoughts? Or does Jackson not let you configure the indentation at all?

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html) show that the `PrettyPrinter` interface is only for the `JsonGenerator`.

If you want to customize your YAML output, you have to use the SnakeYAML API directly (which is used by Jackson for YAML processing). SnakeYAML has [similar features to Jackson](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) and there is little reason to use Jackson if you only want to process YAML. Most importantly, it lets you configure YAML formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm looking into SnakeYaml as well, but there are quite a few differences in there. More than that I was curious know if the YAML output is customizable at all using Jackon. For example, you have this feature - https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLGenerator.Feature.html#INDENT_ARRAYS which indents it to a default of 2 spaces, but seems like its not customizable?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 2 space indentation using something similar to the following.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.INDENT_ARRAYS_WITH_INDICATOR, true)
                                .disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.USE_NATIVE_TYPE_ID)
                                .enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES));
```

I found this answer on a github feature request from 2020

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/175